# Redirect From http://example.com/ to http://example.com/?welcome=2

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want my default url to redirect to mydomain.com/?welcome=2

I've tried this but it doesnt work, also I'm using wordpress

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://example.com/?welcome=2$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$  http://example.com/?welcome=2 [L,R=301]
```

The code above will redirect

- http://example.com/ (hompage)

to

- http://example.com/?welcome=2